# Quantum Computing is not Analog Computing. Really?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, quantum-information, computational-physics, quantum-computer

Let's review first these two computation processes to see if in their core fundamental nature are actually different:

**1) Quantum Computing**

One of the properties of quantum mechanics that is exploited in QC is that the qubit is represented as the [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition) of the spin of an atom or electron when subjected to a switching polarity homogeneous z-axis magnetic field $B$  for example for the case of an electron:

[image: spin up spin down]

Discrete logic values of qubit

The electron can be arbitrary land at any of the above states when the external magnetic field $B$ is switched on at a specific magnetic moment (N pole up or down). In the above illustration the z-axis $B$ field assuming it has its magnetic moment vector pointing up (N pole up) for the electron on the left-hand side,  has  its spin precession cone facing up, is called a spin up electron and its magnetic moment vector facing down antiparallel to its spin vector and $B$ field magnetic moment vector *(i.e. electron has negative electric charge therefore its magnetic moment is always antiparallel to its spin angular momentum vector)*. This state is the highest energy state of the electron and represents a discrete value of a logic $1$ qubit. The right hand-side electron, spin down has its magnetic moment aligned parallel to the $B$ field and is in the lowest energy state and is called a discrete value logic $0$ qubit.

Furthermore, we can take advantage of the [magnetic precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession) of the electrons, magnetic vector of electron rotating around 360° the z-axis $B$ field (see blue cone) and apply an analog linear amplitude operator, continuous value, to correspond the the electron's magnetic moment position around the rim of its precession cone assuming we know the precession frequency which depends on the strength of the external magnetic $B$ field (see [Bloch Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) below).

[image: Bloch Sphere]

Bloch Sphere

So, wee see now that we can encode in a single qubit more information than a normal binary bit  since for fully describing its quantum state we need its discrete logic (binary) value 0 or 1 but also its logic 0 analog amplitude operator and also logic 1 analog amplitude operator:

$$
|\psi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle \quad \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C} \quad|\alpha|^{2}+|\beta|^{2}=1
$$

The situation rises exponentially when we have $N$ number of [quantum entangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) qubits where we can encode information translated in binary logic of $2^{\mathrm{N}}$ normal bits.

All the above mentioned is the so called setup phase where we prepare our entangled qubits at the desired quantum state using the magnetic $B$ field accordingly to the computation we want to perform and then zero the $B$ field for an amount of time. During the zero $B$ is when the "magic" happens. The entangled correlated qubits start interfering in superposition and when we switch back the external $B$ field we quickly sample the quantum states of the qubits and voila the answer to the computation asked. Since there is only one basic arithmetic function namely algebraic addition *(i.e. multiplication is sequential addition and division sequential subtraction)* the trick to quantum programming is to set correctly all qubits at the desired quantum state during the setup phase, input of the computation. Notice here, from the computed final answer we extract only the discrete quantum states logic $1$ and $0$ thus binary information as we would have in a normal binary computer.

**2) Analog Computing**

Although over simplified, fundamentally in an analog computer if we want say to add 0.866 with 0.344 we would send these two analog linear current values say 0.866μΑ and 0.344μΑ in a known resistance value ohmic resistor and read the corresponding voltage drop on the resistor. Usually in practice this is done with an analog opamp circuit called adder:

[image: Analog opamp adder]

V1,V2 and V3 analog numbers are added at the output of the circuit $V_{O}$

image source: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392292/adding-large-numbers-in-context-of-analog-computing

$Question:$

We observe above in **case 2** of analog computing, that the computation and input data as well as output are pure analog linear continuous values taking advantage of the natural algebraic analog addition of electric currents phenomenon similar fundamentally to **case 1** quantum computing, where  the total superposition quantum state *(i.e. discrete quantum state with analog operator amplitude values)* of the entangled qubits during the *zero magnetic field phase* where the actual computation takes place and the interfering spins are in superposition thus can take any arbitrary  continuous value (i.e. analog).

**So, if the wave function amplitude is a continuous quantity at the core of the quantum computation (i.e. zero magnetic $B$ field phase) is in that sense, quantum computing actually analog?**

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding of what quantum computing is. In popularisation they often say that "you can store more info" in one qubit because it is described as a vector with real values, but really this is not the strength of quantum computing, it is more involved than that.

Comment: This whole question is a red herring: Sure, quantum computing is "analog" in that the Bloch sphere is a continuous set of possible states, but that doesn't imply anything useful (e.g. it doesn't mean you could implement Shor's algorithm on a classical analog computer!).

Comment: @Frotaur I agree. Because in nature IMHO it is analog and not artificial binary, as any physical processes is. And we know that one of the advantages of analog computing is speed of computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind As in the case of analog computers the computation execution does not need to be algorithmic instructed but is done by a natural analog process.

Comment: @ACuriousMind " it doesn't mean you could implement Shor's algorithm on a classical analog computer!" The question is not asking this but if QC is analog in nature at its core?

Comment: If you want to stress the continuous aspect of QC maybe we can say that quantum computers are their own thing, partly analog and partly digital.

Comment: @Mauricio Yes this is a fair description. In the sense that the quantum state of the qubit is discrete polarized (binary) by the magnetic z-axis field during the setup phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantum computers are like classical analog computers in that they have a continuous state space, and are like classical digital computers in that they have a discrete output space.

Anything beyond that is just opinion about what the words "analog" and "digital" ought to mean. In my experience, quantum computers are rarely called either analog or digital. They're just called quantum.

Comment: Good point. Even conventional computers are like that. There are continuous states inside as well, but there is a stabilization mechanism to discrete states (gate is "open"/"closed") for the purposes of computation.

Comment: In general I agree with benrg therefore I've upvoted his/her answer. However, we cannot ignore that the main computation is done during the relaxed state and is a product of quantum interference  and superposition described by continuous linear wave function and not with discrete states therefore the computation must be identified as analog. We must not forget that the quantum nature is only observed during measurement. When undisturbed the quantum world is described by wave function that is continuous and linear analog as all processes in nature are.

Comment: "Anything beyond that is just opinion about what the words "analog" and "digital" ought to mean". That statement seems to me to run counter to some well established principles in computer science. Could you expand a little on why you reject that background?

Answer (score 3):

Quantum computing is a form of digital not analog computing. I will explain why.

First, let's note that the fact that the physical state space is continuous is not the relevant fact. For the physical state space available to the components (e.g. capacitors and transistors) in a classical digital computer is also continuous. A computer is digital, or not, because of the way if makes use of its components. Two features are important. First, non-linear control feedback is used to push each memory element (each bit) onto a discrete set of states. Secondly, numbers are stored in a digital (such as binary) notation using the bits, not using some other measure such as the length of a physical object or a voltage or something like that. This means that in order to increase the precision of any given calculation, you do not have to re-engineer the precision of the whole device, you just just have to add more bits. Those are the central differences between digital and analog computing.

Now for quantum computing. The available state space is continuous, but in fact the machine does not need to use all of this continuity, and indeed when a quantum computer uses error-correction and fault-tolerant methods (as future machines are likely to do) under correct operation it will only ever explore a discrete set of the states available to it. The error-correcting circuitry ensures this. What is important, and indeed crucial to the computing power of quantum computing, is that it is not necessary to get really close (exponentially close) to any given desired state in order to carry forward the computation. At the end the computer is measured, i.e. projected onto a given basis, and in order to have a viable probability of success (i.e. one bounded to be above, say, one half) the states realized en route only need to be close to the perfect ones with a degree of precision which scales linearly with the number of gates and bits, or sometimes quadratically, but not exponentially.

The above shows how in the quantum case the rough equivalent of a classical digital computer's non-linear feedback onto a discrete set of states is going on.

The other important aspect of digital computing is that to improve the precision or power of the machine you don't have to re-engineer the whole machine; you just add more bits. This too is what happens in quantum computing, only it is qubits not classical bits of course.